# Generate all type of unique possible combinations of a python list

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation, sublist

hello i need to know how can i get all the unique possible combinations of a list in such an interesting way:

eg:

```
myLIST=[70,90,100]
```

i want to make either two or a single digit unique combination..
i.e;

```
final_list=[ { [100 , 70] , [90] } , { [100 , 90] , [70] }]
```

here in this example:
there possible only these two sublists;

as; if i take `[{ [70,100] , [90] }]` or `[{[90,100],[70]}]`
the sublists combinations starts repeating

```
Note : for a list of 5 elements;i just need those combination lists which have either 3 elemnts or two elements
```

eg:`myLIST=[10,20,30,40,50]`

`final_list=[{[10,30,50],[20,40]}] , {[10,50],[20,50,30]}`
and so on..

here i have taken only the sublists of size 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools (a built-in python library) to generate combinations of lists:

```
from itertools import combinations

sample_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
list_combinations = list()
sample_set = set(sample_list)

for n in range(len(sample_set) + 1):
    list_combinations += list(combinations(sample_set, n))

print(list_combinations)
```

returns:

```
[(), ('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

You can find more information about itertools here:
https://datagy.io/python-combinations-of-a-list/